# Why i am getting the error "Constructor is undefined"?

Tags: java, enums, constructor

In the following code @ line 4 & 5 i am getting the error `The constructor DataSourceFactory.DATABASE_TYPE() is undefined`

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

    public enum DATABASE_TYPE {     
        DB2T    { "DB2T url"    },  
        DB2Q    { "DB2Q url"    };

        private final String url;     

        DATABASE_TYPE( String _url ){
            this.url = _url;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }       

    };  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for ( DATABASE_TYPE dt : DATABASE_TYPE.values()){
            System.out.println( dt.getUrl() );

        }
    }
}
```

and if i will add the constructor with no arguments then i am getting the error `Syntax error on token ""DB2T url"", delete this token`.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've put the constructor arguments in braces, not brackets. So this:

```
DB2T    { "DB2T url"    },  
DB2Q    { "DB2Q url"    };
```

should be

```
DB2T("DB2T url"),  
DB2Q("DB2Q url");
```

(As a side-note, I'd personally avoid making your type names shouty like that. Typically enum *values* are shouty, but the names of enums themselves are in PascalCase as normal.)

Answer (score 2):

Constructor invoking is defined by "()". "{}" is array initializer. So, your invokation should be `DB2T("DB2T url"),`